# Excel - How to remove Specific characters in a Cell

Tags: excel

I have a column of data in Excel;

```
079025555018
079025556019
079025557020
079025558021
079025559022
...
```

The values change but the placement of the zeros is constant. I am trying to remove the First Zero and the Zero in the 3rd to last position.

```
79025555518
79025555619
79025555720
...
```

After the values are changed I am trying to add two hyphens

```
79-0255555-18
79-0255556-19
19-0255557-20
...
```

I am playing around with the Trim, Left and Right commands in excel, but am unable to figure this out completely. So far I have only been successful at removing the first zero. I can get the hyphens to add in a separate formula. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does it:

```
=TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(--A1,"0","",2),"00-000000-00")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Always thankful for this community and its people. usually can find answers and even if the solution makes me feel like a fool. I appreciate it that worked brilliantly.

Comment: @Neil when the question is 15 minutes old please consider marking it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Additional question. I am understanding how the text and substitute formula work, but I am playing around with the formula to remove the middle leading zero as well, but seem to keep getting the zero to appear on either side of the hyphen.

Comment: Additional question. I am understanding how the text and substitute formula work, but I am playing around with the formula to remove the middle leading zero as well (example; 79-25555-18), but seem to keep getting the zero to appear on either side of the hyphen when editing the format section or the substitute section solely.

Answer (score 0):

First Formula (I used cell B1):

```
=REPLACE(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)),LEN(A1)-3,1,"-")
```

Second formula (I used cell C1):

```
=CONCAT(LEFT(B1,2),"-",RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-2))
```

Comment: So I was able to utilize your code in order to get two separate columns which then resulted in the following format

00-000000-00 or 79-020638-20

I added a 3rd column which substituted the first zero, which worked like a charm. Now i need to figure out how to nest these three codes.